# Can the formula for calculating the resistivity be used to know the length of a coil of wire?

Tags: power-supply, resistance, resistivity

I am bamboozled after I found that the length of a primary coil of a transformer that I wanted to recoil was approximately 870m.

The wire used was about 0.4mm in diameter, the coil as taking a voltage of 220v, the secondary coil was supposed to give 32v.

When I compared the resistance of the primary coil of a similar transformer (with the same input to output voltage ratio), I found out that the resistance was 120ohms, I plugged the values into the formula for calculating resistivity and I found that the length of the wire I was supposed to use was approximately 870m.

The confusion comes where the length of the wire seems so large but the transformer has a relatively smaller dimensions, of about 5cm in length 2cm in width and 4cm in height.

Comment: Obviously, your expectations were wrong. Do you have any actual question for us? It seems you answered the title question yourself.

Comment: `I found out that the resistance was 120ohms` how did you measure this? Is it possible that you might have measured a *reactance* at 50 Hz maybe? Because this corresponds to ~400 mH which sounds reasonable for an iron-core transformer.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes if you know the wire diameter and material resistivity.

Comment: Won't the thickness of the insulating coating will be significant too? Whatever distance it contributes to overall wire diameter, the copper cross-section area will be reduced by the square of that.

Answer (score 0):

0.4mm diameter is about AWG26 0.125mm^2 so 870m would be about 110 cubic cm, and would thus weigh about 1kg (copper wire is assumed in this answer). I doubt that seems reasonable for the size of transformer you describe.

Number of turns and wire size are what counts, but if you have an *identical* transformer to the one that failed and know the exact wire size then you can estimate the length from resistance. One thing that may be flummoxing and/or bamboozling you is if you accidentally measured the wire size of the secondary, which would tend to use much larger wire than the primary in a mains-powered step-down transformer. It would take a lot more 0.4mm wire length to reach 120Ω than (say) 0.2mm wire. With 0.2mm diameter wire the length would drop to 1/4, and the required mass would drop to 1/16 so more like 60g than 1kg of wire.

In any case, accurate measurement of wire diameter is important- preferably a micrometer (with a light touch lest the wire get squished down), but at least vernier or digital calipers.